# ZoneOffset ZoneId custom serialization

Tags: java, jackson, timezone-offset, json-serialization, zoneid

What is the best way to serialize ZoneId or ZoneOffset from format +03:00 to format +03.00 using Jackson? Or may be there is another way how to change : to .

Comment: The format with the colon is the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can’t persuade the consumer of your JSON to accept that?

Comment: `ZoneId` is harder. It represents an ID of a time zone that in virtually all cases has had and will have different UTC offset through history and future. I don’t see any reasoable way to serialize that to a numeric string, and under no circumstances will the receiver be able to reconstruct the `ZoneId` object at the other end.

Comment: And no, I believe there is no support for `+03.00` with a point/dot neither in Jackson nor in java.time. If we can’t get rid of that requirement, I would use a custom serializer and inside that something like `ZoneOffset.ofHours(3).toString().replace(':', '.')` (this gives `+03.00`).

Comment: Thank you, I resolved this task by custom serializer with replacing ':' by '.'

Answer (score 2):

The zone offset, `+03:00` is already in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format. Therefore, you should educate the publisher/consumer to stick to it. However, if you want to change it in the desired format for any reason, here is how you can do it:

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of("+03:00");
        String formatted = offset.toString().replace(':', '.');
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
+03.00
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this tak I made custom serializer:

```
object ZoneOffsetSerializer : JsonSerializer<ZoneOffset>() {
    override fun serialize(value: ZoneOffset, jsonGenerator: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
        val result = "0".takeIf { value.totalSeconds == 0 } ?: value.toString().replace(':', '.')

        jsonGenerator.writeString(result)
    }
}
```

and used annotation `@JsonSerialize(using = ZoneOffsetSerializer::class)` for necessary fields